# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: connection is closed by foreign host

Tags: java, remote-server

After running my java program, I become the error above. What did I wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shR9e.png)

After running my java program, I want be able to connect to the given windows remote server and send a data file there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs. Code or sample data in images can't be copied  in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. Read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Looking at your code your trying to connect to an http port (80), you should most likely be using port 22 assuming the FTP Server is listening on port 22.  You would have to reach out to the admin if you don't have the sftp server details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added my comment as an answer.

Looking at your code your trying to connect to an http port (80), you should most likely be using port 22 (default ssh port) assuming the FTP Server is listening on port 22. Some sites change this for security reasons.

You would have to reach out to the admin if you don't have the sftp server details.